# Find if multiple characters in a string

Tags: r, grepl

I have a string like this

```
fileName <- 'tyi_myRef_2019_2020'
```

I want to check if any of the following characters
are present in the `fileName` and if yes, assign it to an object.

```
myChar <- c('myPer','myRef','myYe','myQr')
```

The way I did this is:

```
if(grepl('myPer', fileName)) {myObject <- 'myPer'}
if(grepl('myRef', fileName)) {myObject <- 'myRef'}
if(grepl('myYe', fileName)) {myObject <- 'myYe'}
if(grepl('myQr', fileName)) {myObject <- 'myQr'}

myObject
"myRef"
```

Is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: relevant - possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319567/use-grepl-to-search-either-of-multiple-substrings-in-a-text

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sapply` like:

```
myObject <- myChar[sapply(myChar, function(x) {grepl(x, fileName)})]
myObject
#[1] "myRef"
```

or even shorter as @g-grothendieck suggested:

```
myObject <- myChar[sapply(myChar, grepl, fileName)]
```

In case you have more than one hit `myObject` will hold all hits, what is not the case with your `if` statements, which will overwrite. With `myObject[length(myObject)]` you will get the last hit like you do with the `if`'s.

You can also use `|` in the regex and get the match like:

```
myObject <- sub(paste0(".*(", paste(myChar, collapse="|"), ").*"), "\\1", fileName)
```

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks! I have included your suggestion in the answer. Is this OK?

Answer (score 1):

An option is to `paste` them into a single string `collapse` by `|` and feed that as `pattern` in `grepl`.  The `|` will act as `OR` to check if any of the substrings are present in the 'fileName'

```
grepl(paste(myChar, collapse="|"), fileName)
```

Or another option is to extract

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(fileName, paste(myChar, collapse = "|"))
#[1] "myRef"
```

---

If wee need to assign, then

```
myChar[lengths(sapply(myChar, function(x) grep(x, fileName))) > 0]
#[1] "myRef"
```

Answer (score 1):

With `stringr`:

```
 res<-stringr::str_extract_all(fileName,myChar)
   res[lengths(res)>0]
[[1]]
[1] "myRef"
```

With `base`:

```
res<-Map(function(x,y) x[grep(x,y)],myChar,fileName)
res[lengths(res)>0]
$myRef
[1] "myRef"
```